# How do I select from an Oracle table with a timestamp(6)?

Tags: sql, oracle, floating-point, sas, timestamp

In SAS, I create a data set (`dt`) with dates using seconds with 6 fractional decimals:

```
data dt;
  dt_21_aug_2017_23_59_59_999999 = '21aug2017:23:59:59.999999'dt;
  dt_01_jan_1960_23_59_59_999999 = '01jan1960:23:59:59.999999'dt;
run;
```

Then I "format" the data set:

```
data dt_formatted;
     set dt;

     format dt_21_aug_2017_23_59_59_999999 datetime32.6;
     format dt_01_jan_1960_23_59_59_999999 datetime32.6;
run;
```

I can see that the 6 fractional digits are preserved.

I use `dt_formatted` to create an Oracle table:

```
libname tq84_ora  oracle 
   user                     = &ora_user
   password                 = &ora_password
   path                     = &ora_server
;

proc sql;
  create table  tq84_ora.dt_formatted as
  select * from work    .dt_formatted;
quit;
```

The table is created, as desired, with two `timestamp(6)` columns.

If I use *pass through* to query the table with a where condition, the inserted record is returned:

```
proc sql;
  connect to oracle (
    user = &ora_user
    pw   = &ora_password
    path = &ora_server
  );

  select * from connection to oracle (
    select *
    from dt_formatted
    where dt_21_aug_2017_23_59_59_999999 = TO_TIMESTAMP(
        '21AUG2017:23:59:59.999999',
        'DDMONYYYY:HH24:MI:SS.FF',
        'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
      )
  );

  disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

However, If I use the traditional way to select records, no record is returned:

```
proc sql;
  select * from tq84_ora.some_dates_date_format 
  where  dt_21_aug_2017_23_59_59_999999  = '21aug2017:23:59:59.999999'dt;
quit;
```

However, If I select on `dt_01_jan_1960_23_59_59_999999`, the record is returned:

```
proc sql;
  select * from tq84_ora.some_dates_date_format 
  where  dt_01_jan_1960_23_59_59_999999  = '01jan1960:23:59:59.999999'dt;
quit;
```

The reason seems to be a limitation with floating points. Still, this is strange since Oracle clearly stores the 2017 date with 6 digits (that are `9`).

So, what can I do to select the 2017 record with the traditional `proc sql` approach?

Comment: Is the variable coming into SAS as a datetime value?  If you pull the record over using the SQL passthru syntax in your first step into a SAS dataset can you then use the datetime literal to select it from the SAS dataset?  That should help tell if the issue is in the conversion of the DT literal into actual numbers or in the pushing of the datetime constant into the remote database.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a LIKE and take the date as a string.

```
data test;
    format new_date $50.;
    set work.entity;

    new_date=datefrom;
run;

proc sql outobs=1;
    select * from work.test where new_date like '%189%';
run;
```

datefrom was in a date format.
new_date react as a string.

In your case you could do a select statement with in the where clause :

```
    proc sql;
        select * from work.dt_formatted where dt_21_aug_2017_23_59_59_999999 like '%jan2017:%' 
OR dt_21_aug_2017_23_59_59_999999 like '%feb2017:%' 
    ...
    ;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in some SAS formats where it cannot properly report the digits to the right of the decimal place for a number that is larger than 1,000,000,000.  Note that the DATETIME format actually works, but other SAS formats like BEST, F and COMMA do not.  Perhaps this is impacting how SAS transfers the constant to the remote database.  I would recommend opening a ticket with SAS support to report this issue.

```
data test;
  length int frac 8 format $42 str $26 dec $8;
  frac=0.999999;
  format int comma15. frac 8.6 ;
  do int =10**9-1 to 10**9+1 by 1 ;
    do format='datetime26.6','F26.6','best26.6','comma26.6';
      str=putn(int+frac,format);
      dec=scan(str,-1,'.');
      num9s=countc(dec,'9');
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

[image]